# Can I use a coffee cup Stirling engine to generate power?

Tags: generator

I want to generate electricity to power an led using a coffee cup Stirling engine. Will it provide enough power, or should I use something like a gearbox? Or will it do the job in the first place? Extra info: I will use quick lime to heat the water inside the cup. Link to the engine I will use: https://amzn.to/3cAB1iM

Comment: In my experience, these only generate enough power to keep themselves spinning - not enough to drive any load. LEDs don't need much power though... In any case your generator would have to be coupled very efficiently.

Comment: Keep in mind that LED driver circuits typically pulse the LED at anywhere from 50 Hz to 1 kHz.  You will waste energy and degrade the LED if you drive with DC current.